# listview position value not exceeding 5

Tags: android, listview, position, listitem, getview

I have used a custom adapter to populate list view which is populating correctly using data. I have some textview which is getting data from database. when i click update it should get data from textview and present it to edittext for correction or updation. but it is not working correctly. Click on update some time enable more that two rows for updation and also data change from the original one.

Please help to correct this

UpdatePathi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.app.nirvachan.rssb.UpdatePathiActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorHead"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Pathi ID"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Pathi Name"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Center ID"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Point ID"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Contact No"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:text="Options"
            android:padding="5dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listpathi"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom_Pathi_Item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorList"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutEdit"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtPathiID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtPathiName"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtCenterID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtPointID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtContactNo"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_edit"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_delete"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutUpdate"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/etPathiID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/etPathiName"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/etCenterID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/etPointID"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/etContactNo"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_update"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

UpdatePathiActivity.java

```
package com.app.nirvachan.rssb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UpdatePathiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listPathi;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String pathiID, pathiName, contactNo;
    int centerID, pointID;

    private static String url_get_pathi = "http://onkararts.000webhostapp.com/php/rssb_get_pathi.php";
    private static String url_get_point = "http://onkararts.000webhostapp.com/php/rssb_get_point.php";
    private static String url_get_center = "http://onkararts.000webhostapp.com/php/rssb_get_center.php";
    private static String url_update_pathi = "http://onkararts.000webhostapp.com/php/rssb_update_pathi.php";
    private static String url_delete_pathi = "http://onkararts.000webhostapp.com/php/rssb_delete_pathi.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PATHIS = "pathis";
    private static final String TAG_CENTERS = "centers";
    private static final String TAG_POINTS = "points";
    private static final String TAG_POINT_ID = "Point_ID";
    private static final String TAG_POINT_NAME = "Point_Name";
    private static final String TAG_CENTER_ID = "Center_ID";
    private static final String TAG_CENTER_NAME = "Center_Name";
    private static final String TAG_PATHI_ID = "Pathi_ID";
    private static final String TAG_PATHI_NAME = "Pathi_Name";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT_NO = "Contact_No";


    ArrayList<Pathi> pathi_Data;
    UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter a_pathi;
    User[] centers_data, points_data;
    SpinAdapter a_centers, a_points;
    JSONArray centers, points, pathis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_pathi);

        listPathi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listpathi);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        UpdatePathiActivity.getCenters gc = new UpdatePathiActivity.getCenters();
        gc.execute();

        UpdatePathiActivity.getPoints gp = new UpdatePathiActivity.getPoints();
        gp.execute();

        UpdatePathiActivity.getPathis gr = new UpdatePathiActivity.getPathis();
        gr.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class getPathis extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Pathi>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Pathi> pathis) {
            a_pathi = new UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter(UpdatePathiActivity.this, pathis);
            listPathi.setAdapter(a_pathi);
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Pathi> doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_get_pathi, "GET", params);

                Log.d("Getting Result", json.toString());

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // vehicles found
                    // Getting Array of vehicles
                    pathis = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PATHIS);
                    pathi_Data = new ArrayList<Pathi>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pathis.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = pathis.getJSONObject(i);
                        Pathi r = new Pathi(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_PATHI_ID)), c.getString(TAG_PATHI_NAME), Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_CENTER_ID)), Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_POINT_ID)), Long.parseLong(c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NO)));
                        pathi_Data.add(i,r);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.getMessage().toString();
            }
            return pathi_Data;
        }
    }

    public class updatePathi extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pathi_ID", pathiID));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pathi_Name", pathiName));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Center_ID", centerID+""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Point_ID", pointID+""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Contact_No", contactNo));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_pathi,"POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int r = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(r == 1){
                    z = "Record Updated Successfully";
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
                else{
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Pathi Updation Failed";
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException ex) {
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
            return z;
        }
    }

    public class deletePathi extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pathi_ID", pathiID));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_pathi,"POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int r = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(r == 1){
                    z = "Record Deleted Successfully";
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
                else{
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Pathi deletion Failed";
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException ex) {
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
            return z;
        }
    }

    public class PathiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        List<Pathi> pathiList;

        public PathiAdapter(Context context, List<Pathi> pathiList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.pathiList = pathiList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pathiList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Pathi getItem(int position) {
            return pathiList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return pathiList.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }

        private class ViewHolder{
            LinearLayout l_edit;
            TextView t_pathiID;
            TextView t_pathiName;
            TextView t_centerID;
            TextView t_pointID;
            TextView t_contactNo;
            ImageButton b_edit;
            ImageButton b_delete;
            LinearLayout l_update;
            TextView e_pathiID;
            EditText e_pathiName;
            Spinner e_centerID;
            Spinner e_pointID;
            EditText e_contactNo;
            ImageButton b_update;
        }

        UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder d_holder = null;

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pathi_item, null);
                d_holder = new UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder();
                d_holder.t_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiID);
                d_holder.t_pathiName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiName);
                d_holder.t_contactNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNo);
                d_holder.t_centerID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCenterID);
                d_holder.t_pointID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPointID);
                d_holder.b_edit = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
                d_holder.b_delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
                d_holder.l_edit = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdit);
                d_holder.l_update = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUpdate);
                d_holder.e_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);
                d_holder.e_pathiName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiName);
                d_holder.e_contactNo = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);
                d_holder.e_centerID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etCenterID);
                d_holder.e_pointID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPointID);
                d_holder.b_update = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
                convertView.setTag(d_holder);
            }
            else{
                d_holder = (UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Pathi row_pos = pathiList.get(position);
            d_holder.t_pathiID.setText(String.valueOf(row_pos.getPathiID()));
            d_holder.t_pathiName.setText(row_pos.getPathiName());
            d_holder.t_contactNo.setText(String.valueOf(row_pos.getContactNo()));
            d_holder.t_centerID.setText(String.valueOf(row_pos.getCenterID()));
            d_holder.t_pointID.setText(String.valueOf(row_pos.getPointID()));

            d_holder.b_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    View view = listPathi.getChildAt(position);
                    TextView u_pathiID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);
                    EditText u_pathiName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiName);
                    EditText u_contactNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);
                    Spinner u_centerID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.etCenterID);
                    Spinner u_pointID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.etPointID);
                    LinearLayout u_edit = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdit);
                    LinearLayout u_update = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutUpdate);
                    Pathi pathi  = getItem(position);
                    u_pathiID.setText(String.valueOf(pathi.getPointID()));
                    u_pathiName.setText(pathi.getPathiName());
                    u_contactNo.setText(String.valueOf(pathi.getContactNo()));
                    u_centerID.setAdapter(a_centers);
                    u_centerID.setSelection(pathi.getCenterID());
                    u_pointID.setAdapter(a_points);
                    u_pointID.setSelection(pathi.getPointID());
                    u_edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    u_update.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            d_holder.b_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View view = listPathi.getChildAt(position);
                    TextView u_pathiID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);
                    EditText u_pathiName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiName);
                    EditText u_contactNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);
                    Spinner u_centerID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.etCenterID);
                    Spinner u_pointID = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.etPointID);
                    pathiID = u_pathiID.getText().toString();
                    pathiName = u_pathiName.getText().toString();
                    contactNo = u_contactNo.getText().toString();
                    centerID = a_centers.getItem(u_centerID.getSelectedItemPosition()).getId();
                    pointID = a_centers.getItem(u_pointID.getSelectedItemPosition()).getId();
                    UpdatePathiActivity.updatePathi ur = new UpdatePathiActivity.updatePathi();
                    ur.execute();
                }
            });

            d_holder.b_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Pathi row_pos = pathiList.get(position);
                    pathiID = String.valueOf(row_pos.getPathiID());
                    //Toast.makeText(UpdateCenterActivity.this, centerID+centerName+address+contactNo+eMailID+secretaryName+secretaryNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    UpdatePathiActivity.deletePathi dr = new UpdatePathiActivity.deletePathi();
                    dr.execute();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class getCenters extends AsyncTask<String, String, User[]> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User[] centers) {
            a_centers = new SpinAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, centers);
        }


        @Override
        protected User[] doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_get_center, "GET", params);

                Log.d("Getting Result", json.toString());

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // vehicles found
                    // Getting Array of vehicles
                    centers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CENTERS);
                    centers_data = new User[centers.length()+1];
                    // looping through All Vehicles
                    centers_data[0] = new User();
                    centers_data[0].setId(0);
                    centers_data[0].setName("Please Select Center Name");
                    for (int i = 0; i < centers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = centers.getJSONObject(i);
                        centers_data[i+1] = new User();
                        centers_data[i+1].setId(c.getInt(TAG_CENTER_ID));
                        centers_data[i+1].setName(c.getString(TAG_CENTER_NAME));
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.getMessage().toString();
            }
            return centers_data;
        }
    }


    public class getPoints extends AsyncTask<String, String, User[]> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User[] points) {
            a_points = new SpinAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, points);
        }


        @Override
        protected User[] doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_get_point, "GET", params);

                Log.d("Getting Result", json.toString());

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // vehicles found
                    // Getting Array of vehicles
                    points = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POINTS);
                    points_data = new User[points.length()+1];
                    points_data[0] = new User();
                    points_data[0].setId(0);
                    points_data[0].setName("Please Select Point Name");
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = points.getJSONObject(i);
                        points_data[i+1] = new User();
                        points_data[i+1].setId(c.getInt(TAG_POINT_ID));
                        points_data[i+1].setName(c.getString(TAG_POINT_NAME));
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.getMessage().toString();
            }
            return points_data;
        }
    }

}
```

Please find screenshot of the problem

Here when I click on 6th item
[image]

Here when I click on 7th item
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code, your `onClickListener` should be outside `if` `else` block

```
public class PathiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<Pathi> pathiList;

public PathiAdapter(Context context, List<Pathi> pathiList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pathiList = pathiList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pathiList.size();
}

@Override
public Pathi getItem(int position) {
    return pathiList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return pathiList.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

private class ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout l_edit;
    TextView t_pathiID;
    TextView t_pathiName;
    TextView t_centerID;
    TextView t_pointID;
    TextView t_contactNo;
    ImageButton b_edit;
    ImageButton b_delete;
    LinearLayout l_update;
    TextView e_pathiID;
    EditText e_pathiName;
    Spinner e_centerID;
    Spinner e_pointID;
    EditText e_contactNo;
    ImageButton b_update;
}

UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder d_holder = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pathi_item, null);
        d_holder = new UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder();
        d_holder.t_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiID);
        d_holder.t_pathiName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiName);
        d_holder.t_contactNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNo);
        d_holder.t_centerID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCenterID);
        d_holder.t_pointID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPointID);
        d_holder.b_edit = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        d_holder.b_delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        d_holder.l_edit = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdit);
        d_holder.l_update = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUpdate);
        d_holder.e_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);
        d_holder.e_pathiName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiName);
        d_holder.e_contactNo = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);
        d_holder.e_centerID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etCenterID);
        d_holder.e_pointID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPointID);
        d_holder.b_update = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);          

        convertView.setTag(d_holder);
    }
    else{
        d_holder = (UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    d_holder.b_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked at :" +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });   

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer got me correct position value but if i want to get the child at that position and then get textview associated with that child i got nullpointerexception.

Comment: here is the code inside button click i want to use --- View view = listPathi.getChildAt(position);   TextView u_pathiID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);

Comment: @onkarverma d_holder.t_pathiID and u_pathiID are different or same?

Comment: You must have all the text in your `pathiList`, so why don't you just display the data from your `pathiList` depeding upon `position`

Comment: they are same ... basically what i want to do is when i click edit button the texview is going to convert to edittext for edit. so i want to populate the textview (t_pathiName) value to edittext (e_pathiName).

Comment: @AyushKhare yes i am getting the data from pathiList only... i want to populate that data to d_holder.e_pathiID. how i can set that. Please guide ?

Comment: Please paste your `Pathi` model class

Comment: public class Pathi {

    private int pathiID;
    private String pathiName;
    private int centerID;
    private int pointID;
    private long contactNo;

    public Pathi(int pathiID, String pathiName, int centerID, int pointID, long contactNo) {
        this.pathiID = pathiID;
        this.pathiName = pathiName;
        this.centerID = centerID;
        this.pointID = pointID;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    getter setter here
}

Comment: @AyushKhare i have updated my question with all my code. please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

just chnge this code in your `getView`

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pathi_item, null);
        d_holder = new UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder();
        d_holder.t_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiID);
        d_holder.t_pathiName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPathiName);
        d_holder.t_contactNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNo);
        d_holder.t_centerID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCenterID);
        d_holder.t_pointID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPointID);
        d_holder.b_edit = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        d_holder.b_delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        d_holder.l_edit = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdit);
        d_holder.l_update = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUpdate);
        d_holder.e_pathiID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);
        d_holder.e_pathiName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPathiName);
        d_holder.e_contactNo = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);
        d_holder.e_centerID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etCenterID);
        d_holder.e_pointID = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPointID);
        d_holder.b_update = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);          

        convertView.setTag(d_holder);
    }
    else{
        d_holder = (UpdatePathiActivity.PathiAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    d_holder.b_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked at :" +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });   

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i want to use position value to get the child textview. how can i achieve that. Code i am trying is :  View view = listPathi.getChildAt(position);
                    TextView u_pathiID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);

Comment: View view = listView.getChildAt(position);
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.etPathiID);

Comment: what do you want with that textview view you can direct access it

Comment: Updated the question. please look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

Make Your `Listview's` `onClickListener` outside of the `if` and `else`

```
     if()
      {

      }
     else
      {

      }

   d_holder.b_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked at :" +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```